# Openmp parallelize vector of objects

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, openmp

I have a vector of objects, each an instance of a machine learning agent class. For the purposes of this task, it's only important that each instance of this class must run a complicated costly run() function that does a lot of different things with various data structures stored inside that object. It also uses a couple variables defined outside the class but that can be fixed if necessary - the objects don't need to interact with each other or global variables when run() is executed. Now, the number of agents in this vector is very small and is typically equal to the number of CPU cores..

I've run a test and it only gives a ~2.6 speed-boost with 8 threads on an 8-core processor, not ideal. The function is limited to only use ~17ms per loop. Simplified, it looks like this:

```
vector <MLAgent> agent;
float learning_speed = .01;
size = agent.size();
#pragma omp parallel for num_threads(num_CPU * (size > num_CPU) + size * (size <= num_CPU))
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
agent[i].run(learning_speed);
```

How can this be improved? Would storing the agents in a different way help? Is it important that the run function doesn't use any global variables? Parallelizing parts of run() is basically not an option - it's far too complicated and integrated.

Comment: First things first, the number of thread used is not the most critical information for scalability. The number of core is much more important : running 8 threads on 4 core does not make your code 8 times faster. Thus, the question is then : what is the specification of your processor? Besides, not all code scale. If `run` is memory-bound then this is completely normal to get such a speed up. The thing is we have no idea of what the code does so we cannot really help you. The time of the loop is another critical information we do not have impacting the scalability. Please provide more infos.

Comment: @JérômeRichard I've edited the question per your instructions (each thread runs for 17ms, 8 core CPU) except for the memory bound thing: run() accesses and updates large matrices (armadillo mat type) but all that data is stored within the same object as the function itself, so each thread gets its own object to work with. Is that what you mean by memory bound? Does it matter where that data is stored?

Comment: Memory bound means that the memory subsystem cannot provide data fast enough for the processor to stretch it's legs. If memory bandwidth is the bottleneck, throwing more cores (which rely on the same memory subsystem) at the problem will not give a speedup.

Answer (score 0):

1. Do not specify the number of threads: leave that to the environment variable.
2. Unless the iterations take exactly the same amount of time, use `schedule(dynamic,1)` which gives the operating system the liberty to assign any task to any core.
3. Write idiomatic C++: `for ( auto& a : agent ) a.run()`.

Comment: Will do! Could you clarify: will using idiomatic C++ possibly improve performance or is it just for convenience's sake?

Comment: Same perfromance, just looks cleaner and less chance of off-by-one errors.